# Couldn't match expected type ‘Char -> [Char] -> t’ with actual type ‘Char’

Tags: haskell

I wrote a function for replacing the certain elements in a list with giving element.

```
subst :: Eq t => t -> t -> [t] -> [t]
subst a b [] = []
subst a b (x:xs) = if a == x
                   then b : subst a b xs
                   else
                   subst a b xs
```

when I tested it with 0 1 [0,1,2,3], and here is what it showed

```
*Main> 0 1 [0,1,2,3]

<interactive>:68:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Num (t1 -> [a] -> t2)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t1 a t2. (Num t1, Num a, Num (t1 -> [a] -> t2)) => t2
```

When I tested it with 'e' 'a' "hello", the feedback as shown follows:

```
*Main> 'e' 'a' "hello"

<interactive>:69:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char -> [Char] -> t’
                  with actual type ‘Char’

    • The function ‘'e'’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘Char’ has none
      In the expression: 'e' 'a' "hello"
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = 'e' 'a' "hello"
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:69:1)
```

Can sombody help me explaining what is happening and why it doesn't work?

Comment: In the second test, it clearly wants you to put "subst" before listing the arguments. The first test is more cryptic, even though you skipped "subst" there as well.

Comment: Both of those evaluations of the function you posted work for me, except they don't give the result you expected.  Are you sure you copy/pasted correctly?

Comment: Oh...  You might want to try actually applying the function to the given arguments, e.g., `subst 0 1 [0, 1, 2, 3]` instead of just typing `0 1 [0, 1, 2, 3]` into GHCI.  Still, the result is not what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I have actually fix that, I was confused about why it not working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using GHCi correctly. You must apply your `subst` function to some arguments to evaluate it.

Here's how it should work, assuming your code is in a file called `main.hs`:

```
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/jgt/.ghci
λ :l main
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
λ subst 0 1 [0,1,2,3]
[1]
```

*n.b.* You can ignore the fact that my prompt is `λ`; you can set your own prompt with `:set prompt "λ "`.